# wxPython not finding attributes

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm at wits end. I am trying to work with Gooey and wxPython with Python 3.9.0 Please find a snippet of my code below.

```
@Gooey(program_name="My App", required_cols= 3, optional_cols = 2, default_size=(710, 700))
def parse_args():

    parser = GooeyParser(description='Test App)

    parser.add_argument('Names',
                        action='store',
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Upload Your File Containing Names")

    parser.add_argument('Addresses',
                        action='store',
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Upload Your File Containing Addresses")
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

args = parse_args()
```

When trying to run my code on my work laptop, I receive the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
   __version__ = wx.__version__.VERSION_STRING

AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I have navigated to this folder and can indeed see the `__version__.py` file.

Is there any reason why wxPython would not be able to recognise and import its own attributes? Any help welcomed. I can give more information if needed.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but if `wx.version()` works in 3.9 python try `wx.__version__ = wx.version().split()[0]` or some variation of it, depending on what is expected.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work in 3.9! For some reason these py modules can not be imported! I appreciate the help though. @RolfofSaxony

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that:

```
wx.__version__.VERSION_STRING
```

would ever work, as `wx.__version__` returns a string, as does `wx.version()`

On Linux:
$ python

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 11.1.1 20210531 (Red Hat 11.1.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.__version__
'4.0.7'
>>> wx.version().split()
['4.0.7', 'gtk3', '(phoenix)', 'wxWidgets', '3.0.5']
>>> wx.version().split()[0]
'4.0.7'
>>>
```

If none of the above work, I'd suggest that something is wrong with your installation.
Nothing in your question, offers an explanation as to where the error is generated, as there is no `Traceback`, so given that pure `wx` call demonstrably works under python 3.9, the problem could reside in some other module (pafy), that itself utilises `wx`.
Other than that, I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried simply `import wx` though this gives me the exactly same traceback in my question. It simply informs me there is not attribute called `__version__`. I've tried a reinstallation and still get the same error. I might flag this to the developers